# recyclerView setText Position

Tags: android, text, android-recyclerview

I am working on an android project, where I have set up a cardView inside recyclerView, where I need to be able to setText of the selected cardView.

Currently, this works:

**Adding CardView:**
Press 3 dot Image (on cardview) -> Press on menu (Add cardview) -> (Alert dialog shows up) enter text -> new cardview is added, and title you wrote. Works with position.

**Delete CardView:** 
Press 3 dot Image (on cardview) -> Press on menu (Delete cardview) -> selected cardview deletes. Works with position.

**Change text of CardView:** THIS DOES NOT WORK. I need help to change text on selected cardview. I can set up an alert dialog to enter text, but how do I change text of selected cardview?

**Important Information:** changeLokation (called in code, in switch case), is where I want to change text of cardView.

Menu translation:

- Change text = Ændre navn
- Add sensors to Location = Tilføj Sensor til Lokation (Currently unavailable).
- Add CardView = Add CardView
- Delete CardView = Delete CardView

I appreciate all kind of help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

**CODE IS AS FOLLOWS:**

```
public class lokationRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<lokationRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

List<String> cardList;
String test;

public lokationRecyclerAdapter(List<String> cardList) {
    this.cardList = cardList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.lokationcardview, viewGroup, false );
    return new RecyclerViewHolder( view );
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    cardList.remove( position );
    notifyItemRemoved( position );
    notifyItemRangeChanged( position, cardList.size() );

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int position) {
    recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.ic_circleshape );
    recyclerViewHolder.lokationsName.setText( cardList.get( position ) );
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardList.size();
}

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public int nummer;
    private CardView cardView;
    private Button menuButton;
    private TextView lokationsName;

    public void alertDialog(final View itemView) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder( itemView.getContext() );

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder( itemView.getContext() );
        builder.setCancelable( true );
        builder.setTitle( "Tilføj eller ændre navnet på lokation" );
        builder.setMessage( "Hold styr på dine sensorer ved at oprette lokationer i form af eksempelvis lokaler." );

        final EditText input = new EditText( itemView.getContext() );
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
        input.setMaxLines( 1 );
        input.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
        input.setLayoutParams( lp );
        builder.setView( input );

        builder.setPositiveButton( "Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
                test = input.getText().toString();
                cardList.add( test );
                //lokationsName.setText( test );
                System.out.println( "TEST: " + cardList );
            }
        } );

        builder.setNegativeButton( "Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        } );
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.lokationcard_view );
        menuButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.menuButton );
        lokationsName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.lokationsName );

        itemView.setOnClickListener( this );

        menuButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu( itemView.getContext(), menuButton );
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.lokationpopmenu, popupMenu.getMenu() );

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener( new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {

                            case R.id.changeLokation:
                                System.out.println( "GET ADAPTER POSITION: " + getAdapterPosition() + " CARD LIST: " + cardList );
                                alertDialog( itemView );
                                break;

                            case R.id.addCardView:
                                String lokation = lokationsName.getText().toString();

                                /*if (lokation.equals( "TILFØJ LOKATION" )) {
                                    Toast.makeText( itemView.getContext(), "Du skal ændre navnet på lokation først!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                } else {*/
                                System.out.println( "GET ADAPTER POSITION: " + getAdapterPosition() );
                                //addItem(getAdapterPosition());
                                alertDialog( itemView );
                                System.out.println( "LOKATIONS NAME: " + lokation + " CARDLIST: " + cardList );
                                // }
                                break;

                            case R.id.deleteCardView:
                                if (cardList.size() > 1) {
                                    deleteItem( getAdapterPosition() );
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText( itemView.getContext(), "Du kan ikke slette den sidste CardView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                }
                                break;

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                } );
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        } );

    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code i can see that you are trying to update `lokationsName.setText( test );` directly from the dialog text,I wouldn't recommend doing it that way,you should update your value to your list and call `notifyitemchanged`.

**Example:**

Pass the item position here you would need this to update your item

```
public void alertDialog(final View itemView,int position) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder( itemView.getContext() );

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder( itemView.getContext() );
        builder.setCancelable( true );
        builder.setTitle( "Tilføj eller ændre navnet på lokation" );
        builder.setMessage( "Hold styr på dine sensorer ved at oprette lokationer i form af eksempelvis lokaler." );

        final EditText input = new EditText( itemView.getContext() );
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
        input.setMaxLines( 1 );
        input.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
        input.setLayoutParams( lp );
        builder.setView( input );

        builder.setPositiveButton( "Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
                test = input.getText().toString();
                //change the code here
                cardList.set(position,test);
                notifyItemChanged(position); 
            }
        } );

        builder.setNegativeButton( "Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        } );
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

And in your `RecyclerViewHolder` change the following:

```
public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.lokationcard_view );
        menuButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.menuButton );
        lokationsName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.lokationsName );
        //add this line here
        lokationsName.setText(cardList.get(getAdapterPosition()));

    }
```

Let me know in comments if any concerns.

Comment: Didn't need the last line in RecyclerViewHolder, but you made it work! You're amazing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had tried cardList set so many times, and it bugged out. Now I know why. It was because I forgot to notify

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are doing the setText asynchronously, so you don't have access to your view anymore.

I would try to do so on your recyclerView `myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);` then change your text with the right viewHolder.

Note that if the view has been recycled, it will returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, all changes to your RecyclerView should be accomplished by *first* changing the data that backs your `Adapter` and *then* notifying the adapter of the change. In its simplest form, if you had an array of strings and you wanted to change the third one, your code would look something like this:

```
array[2] = "new text";
adapter.notifyItemChanged(2);
```

This fundamental concept is true regardless of how your data is changing. If you are inserting or deleting values or even resetting the entire data set, you first modify the data and then notify the adapter (with `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemRemoved()`, or `notifyDataSetChanged()`).

In your case, rather than passing the view to your `alertDialog()` method, you should pass that view's adapter position:

```
case R.id.changeLokation:
    alertDialog(getAdapterPosition());
    break;
```

Then, once the user has entered text and clicked the ok button, you'd take your new text and swap it into your list:

```
cardList.remove(position); // this is the argument passed into alertDialog()
cardList.add(position, newText);
```

And finally you'd notify the adapter:

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```